# Where can I check what Xbox 360 console is linked to my Windows Live account?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

A few years ago I set up my Xbox 360 with xbox.com to be able to purchase and download things directly to the console from the website.

That console has since red-ringed and was replaced under warranty. I wanted to buy something today, but I can't tell which Xbox is registered with my account. I suspect it may be the old broken one, and I'd like to update that to make sure the download goes to the right console.

Where on the site can I do this? I don't see anything relevant under "My Account" after I sign in with my Windows Live ID, but maybe I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: @agent86 The plot thickens. How do I tell it which console to download a new purchase to then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no direct way of getting this information. However, you can safely go ahead and make your purchase anyway. Since downloads are associated with your account, they'll appear in the Active Downloads section of the Marketplace pane on the Xbox button menu no matter which Xbox 360 you log in from.

If the current Xbox 360 is *not* considered your primary console, the item in the queue might indicate that it's "Assigned to other console." If this happens, selecting the item and pressing A should bring up an option to download **all** items. Choosing to do so should update your account to consider the current system as your primary Xbox 360, and downloads will happen automatically when you log in from that point forward.

Microsoft has a [Knowledgebase Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919422) on this topic that might also contain relevant information, and Major Nelson did a [blog post](http://majornelson.com/2009/04/01/how-the-xbox-360-download-queue-works/) when this first became a feature.

I'm not sure if it's necessary to do it manually if you go through the above step, but you may also need to transfer licenses for any content you had originally downloaded on your other console.

To perform a license transfer, on your console, go to the Settings pane. From there, click on Account, and select the License Transfer option. As you can only perform this action every four months, it'll ask you to confirm. Doing so should transfer all of your existing licenses over to your new Xbox 360.

Comment: You beat me to answering this, so I have assimilated my links into your post.  Resistance is futile.

Comment: The "assigned to other console" thing happened to me, so I'll have to buy something else later to see if it really does update. :)